# Excel Index Match with if statement?

Tags: excel, indexing

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets:

sheet 3

```
Column F          Column D         Column K
Supplier A        1234             10
Supplier B        2222             4
```

Sheet 2

```
Column D         Column G
Supplier A       1234 - Other
Supplier B       2222 - Other
```

I am trying to compile an index match formula that will check the item number and supplier name and bring back the value from column K.

But, if the value is 7 or greater, then i want to replace the value and have 'Indefinitely'.

Here's an example:

Sheet 2

```
Column D         Column G         Column P
Supplier A       1234 - Other     Indefinitely 
Supplier B       2222 - Other     4
```

Please can someone show me how to do this?

At the moment my code gives me this:

Sheet 2

```
Column D         Column G         Column P
Supplier A       1234 - Other     Indefinitely 
Supplier B       2222 - Other     Indefinitely
```

Code:

```
=INDEX(IF(Data!K:K<=10,"Indefinitely ",Data!K:K),MATCH('Missed On Sale'!D14&LEFT('Missed On Sale'!G14,(FIND(" -",'Missed On Sale'!G14,1)-1)),Data!F:F&Data!D:D,0))
```

Thanks

Comment: Your formula references sheets that you haven't named. Also, is column G on Sheet 2 used?

Answer (score 0):

=IF(INDEX(Data!K:K,MATCH(D2,Data!F:F,0),0)>=7,"Indefinitely",INDEX(Data!K:K,MATCH(D2,Data!F:F,0),0))

No need for Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: I'd probably use vlookup for this, but you specified MATCH